# integrating sails with OTP login (passwordless)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, sails.js

I am developing my application using sails and I have integrated it with passport using sails-generate-auth to use it for local strategy(username and password). I want to have another strategy of OTP based login and no password.

I am trying to integrate [passwordless](https://github.com/florianheinemann/passwordless) with sails and one of the step is setting up middleware

```
app.use(passwordless.sessionSupport());
app.use(passwordless.acceptToken({ successRedirect: '/'}));
```

How do I complete this step in Sails?